# How do you install python3.6 on Ubuntu Core

Tags: python3, ubuntu-core

How do you install python3.6 (or any other 3rd party software) on Ubuntu Core?

I could perhaps create a snap and make a local install with --dangerous --devmode etc but how do I maintain such a snap in the longer run?

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a development environment, then you should check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/888267), about the `classic` snap, which is to provide a chroot with a *classic* console development experience. You can then install Python 3.6 normally through packages or by building from source, here, to develop with.

If however, what you want is a specific Python version to depend on in a package which you intend to ship and run on Ubuntu core, you will need to build that specific version of Python, and any additional libraries you may need for it, and include it within your snap package.

Comment: So I need a copy of python3.6 for every snap i want to ship.