# How to start a python file with Ubuntu Core 16 and Raspberry pi

Tags: python, snap, ubuntu-core, docker, raspberrypi

How can I start a simple .py in Ubuntu Core 16 and Raspberry Pi? because I'm sitting since 10 hours to get a simple python file running.

What I tried:

Set it up with snap classic and sudo apt-get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Result: No command name "add-apt-repository" exist

Next try, setting up docker snap and write a startup program for docker and your python file:

I load the Sourcecode with the docker file from Git into my raspberry
and first connect docker to `docker:home` with the command:

```
sudo snap connect docker:home
```

after connecting it I navigate to the folder with the Project and the Dockerfile in it and try to run the file with the line from the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#test-docker-installation):

```
docker build -t pythonproject
```

with the result: "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.

I also tried it the normal way with docker run:

```
docker run docker_file_name
```

Result:

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

**So have someone an Idea how to run a simple python project on Ubuntu Core 16?**

Because at the moment I don't know any reason why to use Ubuntu Core 16 when no tutorial is working and a single python project can't be run after 10 hours on working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install python3.6 on Ubuntu Core](https://askubuntu.com/q/992304/301745)

Comment: I also tried classic mode like the answer on your question and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that can't possible be the right way, but it does get you to the end result you want. If you follow [this tutorial](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/01/09/how-to-snap-introducing-classic-confinement) to create a snap and include python as a part plugin, it will install python as it install the local snap.

I created a hello world git repository, then did that procedure using my hello world repository as the source. The snap that was created was [worthless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089325/can-i-run-a-python-package-with-snap-on-ubuntu-core), but it did install python!

Now `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` and I can use it to run files I create locally.

Aside, I think the right way is to to install from source to use it in a development environment or install it as a plugin with your code as a snap for a production thing, as noted in the answer in the comments. But those ways seem harder than this cheater route.