# Can I run a python package with snap on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: python, ubuntu-core

I wrote a python package on a Debian-machine that I am trying to port over to Ubuntu Core (it comes preloaded on the hardware I want to use). On Debian, I was able to simply pull my code from git and do `python3 -m mypackage "somearg"`. On Core, I would like to try to implement this as a snap since that method appears to be strongly preferred.

I [figured out how to](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/developer-setup) install the classic snap to get the `snapcraft` build tool. I created a snap and linked my git repository. Then I installed my snap locally, but it doesn't create any binaries.

I presume this is because I didn't create any instructions to do that. I need to somewhere supply a command that says the thing to do with all this source code is to run it with a certain python command.

How do I tell me snapcraft to turn my python package into a binary that runs that package (and pass an argument)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare an app within `snapcraft.yaml`

   ```
   ...
   apps:
     ...
     your-app:
       command: app-launcher
   ...
   ```
2. Then `app-launcher` can be just simple shell script

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   python3 -m mypackage $@

   #if some arguments have space in some arguments use command below
   #python3 -m mypackage $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 ...
   ```

To call command by user:

```
your-app:app-launcher "somearg"
```

**References:**

- [snapcraft.io: commands-and-aliases](https://snapcraft.io/docs/commands-and-aliases)
- [snapcraft.io: defining-a-command](https://snapcraft.io/docs/defining-a-command)
- [SO: Propagate all arguments in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4824590/724406)