# How to run a Python script on Ubuntu Core 20

Tags: snap, python3, ubuntu-core

I would like to run a Python script on Ubuntu Core 20 without making a snap.

How can I do it - is it possible?

Comment: Run `python3 your_script`? Your question is a bit unclear. You should [edit] it and add more background information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Bodo I don't believe python is included in Ubuntu Core by default.

Comment: Lucan did you try and install an existing Python snap first, like [this one](https://snapcraft.io/python38)? If you need a newer version, I think you have to make your own Python snap.

Comment: Also see here: [How to start a python file with Ubuntu Core 16 and Raspberry pi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089302/how-to-start-a-python-file-with-ubuntu-core-16-and-raspberry-pi)

Comment: ok thank you for the answer